# Wordpress localhost ftp

Tags: php, macos, wordpress, localhost

I have wordpress running on my localhost on mac Lion.

Everytime I try to install or delete plugins it asks me for hostname, ftp username and ftp password.

I configured my localhost to 127.0.0.1, but I have never configured the ftp username and password for my localhost. How can I get which user and password it's by default?

I have tried almost every user and pass I have on mysql, my osx admin, etc. with no results.

Any ideas?

Comment: It should work on localhost. Check directory permissions.

Comment: yeah, but what's my ftp username and pass? I never set it on any field :S

Comment: Like alexn said. Just make sure your file permissions are at least 755 and it should stop asking you for permissions. Or even better, just download the plugins and place them into the plugins folder. Also, make sure localhost is setup properly in your http.conf file as a virtual host.

Comment: Have you considered Googling `mac os x ftp default password`? Or `mac os x configure ftp`? Both queries may help find what you need.

Comment: change the permission of the wordpress directory. and add `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` in wp-config.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, WordPress can be a bit fussy about permissions and ownership when it comes to  self-update without FTP, so using FTP to localhost is a perfectly valid tactic, I'd say. But as others have said, just ensuring that everything from your WordPress root directory on downwards is writable by the PHP process, and owned by the same user, may well be enough to avoid the need for FTP.

If you do want to use FTP, are you sure you've [enabled the FTP server](http://www.itworld.com/software/191971/enable-ftp-server-mac-os-x-lion)? If so, you should just use a user who has permission to get to the directory via FTP (you can test with the command-line ftp tool.) As my sites are set up in my personal `Sites` directory, I just use my normal username and password (e.g. for `/Users/matt/Sites/whatever` I log in as `matt`.)

Other things to check: What happens if you try `ftp localhost` on the command line? Can you log in there?

Answer (score 73):

**Update** as mentioned by Chaudhry Waqas in comments it might be sufficient to just add `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` to `wp-config.php`, so please try this first as it's safer not to change access rights if not necessary

> **WARNING:** only do this on your local computer, it's a huge security risk on a public installation!
>
> I haven't tried it but as mentioned by @misterfancypants comment, changing those settings only for `wp-content/plugins/` should be sufficient
> **updated** to incorporate this info

This one worked for me

```
$ cd /Users/<username>/Sites
# (wordpress = name of the directory, change as needed)
$ sudo chown -R :_www wordpress
$ sudo chmod -R g+w wordpress
```

and then add following in wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

found on http://soderlind.no/running-wordpress-locally-on-mac-os-x-lion/#crayon-533a956214a8e343167867

Cheers Can

Comment: This worked for me on a mac after WP started complaining about FTP credentials when trying to update plugins.

Comment: This was by far the simplest solution. If anyone gets confused by this, make sure to replace 'wordpress' to the name of your wordpress directory

` sudo chown -R :_www [your directory name]`

Comment: So it looks like it's setting the group to be `_www`. Is this group documented anywhere as being used by WP?

Comment: @ijoseph WP does not use any group or user specifically by itself afaik, I'm not sure right now what exactly set this group up but as it's part of the linked article it might come from MAMP (most probably), Apache, or macOS. WP shouldn't really care about user/group as long as it's able to read and write its files ;)

Comment: A word of warning here: the chown and chmod commands are too broad. This changes the group and the group permissions on the whole WP installation. You should be able to just change perms on the wp-content/plugins/ directory (and then quickly change them back). All this might be ok on your local environment, but definitely not recommended on a remote server.

Comment: @misterfancypants You're absolutely right, based on the question I assumed it's clear that it's only meant on a private computer / installation, I'll add a warning to my answer, thanks for the hint!

Comment: add only define('FS_METHOD', 'direct'); in config file worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

I fixed it by:

```
cd /var/www
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress
```

Updated on 03-05-2019

```
cd /var/www
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data [YOUR_WORDPRESS_PROJECT_DIR]
```

Comment: Worked for me, but on my OS (Ubuntu) I changed 'wordpress' to 'html' in the second command you list.

Comment: wordpress is just placeholder here,  it should be replaced by your root of the app.

Comment: Instead of this, as @Can suggests, use `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` inside wp-config.php instead. Safer than messing around with permissions.

Answer (score 17):

Add this in your **config.php** file,

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

Answer (score 17):

Actually, problem is that WordPress create a temp file to check the file permissions

and it **compare** that **temp file's owner** with its a **core file's owner** (refer [fileowner()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileowner.php))
**both should match**. in most of the case, it does not match on **localhost** hence we extracted wp files in different user access and PHP has its own user group.

So there are 2 ways to solve this problem.

***Way 1:***

```
cd wordpress
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

and following

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

in wp-config.php

This does not check any **fileowners** just uses the direct file system

***way 2***

set

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress`

This sets the both WordPress into **www-data** use so actually the temp file(which created by WordPress) also comes inside this user, So both fileowners is same so problem solves

More info refer : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_filesystem_method/

Answer (score 6):

Edit the wp-config.php file and add the piece of code mentioned below:

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```